# Please, would you explain me this simple AHK script?

Tags: autohotkey

I modified a simple old AHK script and that basically turns a "." (dot) key pressed to a ":" (colon) as output.

The problem was I needed to map *both* keyboard dots (the numpad one and the one near the right Alt key). Well I somewhat *guessed by trial* how to modify the code and it works but I would like to understand why and how!

I feel AHK documentation has improved much in recent years, but I can't find a way to get to the bottom of this. Here's the code I wish you to explain (**my troubles are primarily on understanding the last line and its connection with the previous ones**):

```
SC034::
NumPadDot:::
:::NumPadDot::SC034
```

Please, provide links to AHK official documentation whenever possible, I'd very appreciate!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SC034::              ; Label for scancode 34 ("."). Since there's no definition
                     ; on this line it's grouped with the next definition
NumPadDot:: :        ; NumPadDot and SC34 will map to ":"
:::NumPadDot::SC034  ; defines a hotstring that outputs "SC034" when you type ":NumPadDot"
```

- Autohotkey Documentation for [Hotstrings](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)
- Autohotkey Documentation for [Hotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Oh yeah, big strike here.
I feel embarrassed now but... I didn't know about [Hotstrings](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)!
That's a so basilar AHK thing... Wow, would you believe it?
That's the shame you get when you learn by googling for code samples and never read not even the beginners tutorial at least! (I could only hope it wasn't already there when I began to juggle with AHK for the first time, some years ago... Who knows? But I'm afraid something similar had to be there anyway...)

Comment: That said, now I understood, thank you so much!
That last line is independent and not related to the previous two, and it is not even relevant in the end.
I think it had to be an attempt to swap the two keys that probably never worked not even in the original code and I though it had to stay there just because it was on the original code but it was totally unnecessary for my purposes and could be safely omitted (shame on me again for not thinking about it a little more by my side!)

Comment: Just one last request: could you please provide further information on AHK scancodes?
I found this searching in official documentation:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys
Is there anything else you know it would be good to know? If not just don't worry, thanks again!